# Scala fs2 Streams with Chunks and Tasks?

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream, fs2

```
  // Simulated external API that synchronously returns elements one at a time indefinitely.
  def externalApiGet[A](): A = ???

  // This wraps with the proper fs2 stream that will indefinitely return values.
  def wrapGetWithFS2[A](): Stream[Task, A] = Stream.eval(Task.delay(externalApiGet))

  // Simulated external API that synchronously returns "chunks" of elements at a time indefinitely.
  def externalApiGetSeq[A](): Seq[A] = ???

  // How do I wrap this with a stream that hides the internal chunks and just provides a stream of A values.
  // The following doesn't compile. I need help fixing this.
  def wrapGetSeqWithFS2[A](): Stream[Task, A] = Stream.eval(Task.delay(externalApiGetSeq))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mark the sequence as a `Chunk` and then use `flatMap` to flatten the stream.

```
def wrapGetSeqWithFS2[A](): Stream[Task, A] =
  Stream.eval(Task.delay(externalApiGetSeq()))
    .flatMap(Stream.emits)
```

(Edited to simplify solution)

Comment: Answer is of course correct.
If I may suggest sth, there is a method
`def emits[F[_],A](a: Seq[A]): Stream[F,A] = chunk(Chunk.seq(a))`

so the code simplifies to:
`Stream.eval(Task.delay(externalApiGetSeq())).flatMap (Stream.emits)`